# Extenion Method for ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

What I am trying to achive is, to add an Extenion Method to `ObservableCollection` which will help to remove all `CollectionChanged` subscribers. Here is the code. HOwever I get some error since I am not able to access the GetInvocationList from CollectionChanged.

How can I do that?

```
public static void RemoveCollectionChanged<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler _event = collection.CollectionChanged;
        if (_event != null) 
        {
            foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in collection.CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList())
            {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(handler.Target, collection))
                {
                    CollectionChanged -= handler;                        
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: "I get some error" doesn't give us nearly enough information, but fundamentally I think you've missed the point of events - they're meant to *hide* subscribers from each other.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure that's true in this case since he already understands the error and isn't asking for it to be diagnosed

Comment: 'The event 'System.Collection.ObjectModel.ObservableCOllection<T>.CollectionChanged' can only appear in left side of += or -='

Comment: @Saroj That error message is pretty self explanatory.  You can only add or remove handlers for the event; you cannot assign the event to a variable.

Comment: @BenAaronson: It's not clear that the OP *does* understand the error - particularly given the "not able to access the GetInvocationList" part. Regardless, *whenever* a question mentions an error, it should include the verbatim text of the error IMO.

Comment: @Servy: I do understand the error, so I did not post the obvious error. However, I am asking is there any alternate solution for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access the invocation list of an event from outside the class itself.

What you can do is wrap the original collection and maintain the event inside this class:

```
MyObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<T> internalCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    //implement collection methods as forwards to internalCollection EXCEPT the changed event
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public MyObservableCollection()
    {
        internalCollection.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => CollectionChanged(s, e);
    }
}
```

Then you can access the invocation list in your custom collection (just the basic pattern, not "production code"!).

But I just saw that the event is marked `virtual`, so it may works even easier (not tested, as never done):

```
MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private List<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> changedHandlers = new List<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>();

    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add
        {
            changedHandlers.Add(value);
            base.CollectionChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            changedHandlers.Remove(value);
            base.CollectionChanged -= value;
        }
     }

     public void RemoveCollectionChanged()
     {
         foreach (var handler in changedHandlers)
             base.CollectionChanged -= handler;
         changedHandlers.Clear();
     }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is how to do what he wants *given* that restriction. If it's impossible, you should say so

Comment: What if you provide an interface method that the extension method uses? .AddEvent() RemoveEvent(). Or maybe just an interface method RemoveCollectionChanged().